# проблема с summernote

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

у меня есть шаблон Thymeleaf с подключенным summernote и полями для ввода текста

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.15/dist/summernote-bs4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.15/dist/summernote-bs4.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03"
            aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/">Список документации</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="main">
    <form th:action="@{/create/submit}" th:object="${document}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="titleDoc">Название документа</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titleDoc" th:field="*{title}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="summernote">Текст документа</label>
            <textarea name="sum" id="summernote" th:field="*{body}"></textarea>
            <script th:inline="javascript">
                $('#summernote').summernote();
            </script>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Сохранить</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть шаблон для отображения документов

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to DocServer</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
</head>


<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03"
            aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/create">Создать документ<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/">Список документации</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Поиск документации" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Поиск</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>


    <div class="main">
        <div th:each="document:${documents}">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form th:action="${document.id}" method="post" ajax="true">
                    <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${document.title}"/>
                    <p class="card-text" th:text="${document.body}"/>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Удалить</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос**
Как отобразить текст без тегов HTML после редактора

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратитесь к [документации](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#fragments) (3.2 More on texts and variables: Unescaped Text)

> If we want Thymeleaf to respect our HTML tags and not escape them, we will have to use a different attribute: `th:utext` (for “unescaped text”)

так что видимо следует заменить

```
<p class="card-text" th:text="${document.body}"/>
```

на

```
<p class="card-text" th:utext="${document.body}"/>
```